# SQL: Checking value counts of a column

Tags: sql, count, case

I'd like to check if a column in a table has values with a small number of value counts.

Consider the following table as an example:

```
RowID    |Product
1        | A
2        | A
3        | B
...
200.000  | C
```

the following table is aggregated of the table above:

```
Product    |Count
A          |204
B          |682
C          |553
D          |1402
E          |30855
F          |357
G          |1
H          |542
```

What I'd like to know of the column Product of my table is, whether or not a Product has a count that is less than 5%. And if so, the SQL statement should return: 'Some values of this field have a small number of value counts'

In other words: IF [MinValueCount]/[Count] <= .05 then 'Some values of this field have a small number of value counts' else 'null'

With the example above, I should get: 'Some values of this field have a small number of value counts'
as product G is less than 5% of the total count of products.

how should the SQL statement look like?

With kind regards,

Lazzanova

Answer (score 0):

Use two levels of aggregation.  You can get the total using window functions:

```
select max( 'Some values of this field have a small number of value counts')
from (select product, count(*) as cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over () as total_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt < 0.05 * total_cnt;
```

The use of `max()` in the outer query is just to return one row.  You could also use `fetch` or a similar clause (whatever your database supports):

```
select 'Some values of this field have a small number of value counts'
from (select product, count(*) as cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over () as total_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt < 0.05 * total_cnt
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Wow! :D Again... Thanks Gordon for the quick reply.